# Extract only samples which belong to certain kmeans label

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, k-means

I'm currently performing K-means clustering for a small dataset that I work with.
My dataset contained of two clusters (cluster 0 and cluster 1).
I'm trying to differentiate the different cluster so I can calculate the `Mean squared error` of each feature in each cluster.
For example, my dataset contained of 20 samples which 10 of them cluster around centroid 0, I want to extract all the samples which are in cluster 0 and perform MSE for each feature over that sub-set of samples.

Here's a snippet of the code below:

```
xX = []

for sample in X:
    sample = list(sample)
    for index in range (len(X)):
        if labels[index] == 0:
            if sample not in xX:
                xX.append(sample)
```

`X` is a `numpy.ndarray` which contains all the samples with different features.
`labels` are of type `kmeans.labels_`, which is also a `numpy.ndarray` and represent the cluster each sample belong to (either `0` or `1`). `xX` is just a `list` which I want to hold the samples belong to each cluster separately.

My current code fail to extract the samples which belong to centroid 0, instead, it ignores my if statement (`if labels[index] == 0`), and just add the whole dataset into my new list `xX`.

If someone can help me with understanding what am I doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

Edit: Here's how my X data looks like:

```
array([[5923210.22, 14.25, 1668.52, 1495373778450.11],
       [1109272.57, 7.47, 49.75, 1495411802900.06],
       [178397.30, 11.67, 245.61, 1495318964821.19],
       [1871514.94, 24.97, 678.05, 1495377767231.84],
       [4501604.93, 42.10, 1252.70, 1495420897842.18]])
```

This is how my labels looks like:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: You should be able to select all the X values with label 0 in one shot by doing `X[labels==0]`. Can you post a few lines of your X and labels data if you want more help?

Comment: @KenSyme I have edited my post, please tell me if anything else is needed in order to for you to try helping, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with your code is the outer loop - you are looping over your samples and then ignoring the sample and looping over all your labels. For every sample you are re-finding all the 0 labels and adding sample that number of times. That's why you need to check if the sample already exists - otherwise you get each sample 3 times (once for each 0 in the labels).

You could just bin the outer loop - it isn't helping you at all - and you will get what you are after

```
xX = []

for index in range (len(X)):
    if labels[index] == 0:
        xX.append(X[index])
```

But there is a much better way - bin all the loops and do a direct lookup using numpy.

```
X[labels == 0]
```

This will return a boolean array where the positions of the true are for the 0 label. Then it will lookup up in X the rows which have a true value in the same position. This is much faster and cleaner. Both methods get the same result

```
[[  5.92321022e+06   1.42500000e+01   1.66852000e+03   1.49537378e+12]
 [  1.10927257e+06   7.47000000e+00   4.97500000e+01   1.49541180e+12]
 [  4.50160493e+06   4.21000000e+01   1.25270000e+03   1.49542090e+12]]
```

Comment: Thank you Ken, your answer solved my problem, I understand my mistake now.